# Custom sort order string delimiters

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How can I apply custom sorting to sort the following?

```
<maps>
  <domain>pics.siteB.com</domain>
  <domain>subdomain1.siteA.com</domain>
  <domain>pics.siteA.org</domain>
  <domain>validdomain</domain>
  <domain>siteD.com</domain>
  <domain>sub-subdomain4.subdomain.siteC.com</domain>
  <domain>sub-subdomain1.subdomain.siteC.com</domain>
  <domain>subdomain1.siteA.net</domain>
<maps>
```

I tried following, then it sorts in a weird way, and removes the entry when the delimite isn't available.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*">
  <!-- using <xsl:variable> throws error here -->
  <xsl:sort select="string-join(reverse(tokenize(domain, '\.')[position() lt last()]), '.')"></xsl:sort>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Expected output:

1. Get the last but one token, like `siteA`, `siteB`, `siteC`, etc
2. Get the last token after delimiter, like, `com`, `net`, `org`, etc
3. Reverse the rest of the tokens before last but 2, like `pics`, `subdomain1`, `sub-subdomain1.subdomain`, etc
4. sort on this text

```
<maps>
  <domain>subdomain1.siteA.com</domain>
  <domain>subdomain1.siteA.net</domain>
  <domain>pics.siteA.org</domain>
  <domain>pics.siteB.com</domain>
  <domain>sub-subdomain1.subdomain.siteC.com</domain>
  <domain>sub-subdomain4.subdomain.siteC.com</domain>
  <domain>siteD.com</domain>
  <domain>validdomain</domain>
<maps>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55683106/how-to-normalize-xml-on-reverse-domain-name-sorting-and-custom-filtering

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes, it's related, but not exactly duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the strings by which you want the domains to be sorted are:

```
<domain>siteB com pics</domain>
<domain>siteA com subdomain1</domain>
<domain>siteA org pics</domain>
<domain>validdomain</domain>
<domain>siteD com</domain>
<domain>siteC com subdomain sub-subdomain4</domain>
<domain>siteC com subdomain sub-subdomain1</domain>
<domain>siteA net subdomain1</domain>
```

you could use:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/maps">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="domain">
            <xsl:sort>
                <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(., '\.')" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[position() ge last() - 1], reverse($tokens[position() lt last() - 1])"/>
            </xsl:sort>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce the result shown in your question.

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9F