# Remove non-identical duplicate nodes (considering default values when tags aren't present)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I've a following-up question on the earlier post:
[How to normalize XML on reverse domain name sorting and custom filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55683106/how-to-normalize-xml-on-reverse-domain-name-sorting-and-custom-filtering)

There's few hundreds of duplicate tag removal questions out there. I attempted to remove duplicate  nodes based on the logic by going through them,  but it doesn't seem to work:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<?tapia chrome-version='2.0' ?>
<mapGeo>
  <a>blah</a>
  <b>blah</b>
  <maps>
    <mapIndividual>
      <src>
        <scheme>https</scheme>
        <domain>photos.yahoo.com</domain>
        <path>somepath</path>
        <query>blah</query>
      </src>
      <loc>C:\var\tmp</loc>
      <x>blah</x>
      <y>blah</y>
    </mapIndividual>
    <mapIndividual>
      <src>
        <domain>photos.yahoo.com</domain>
        <path>somepath</path>
        <query>blah</query>
      </src>
      <loc>C:\var\tmp</loc>
      <x>blah</x>
      <y>blah</y>
    </mapIndividual>
    <mapIndividual>
      <src>
        <scheme>tcp</scheme>
        <domain>map.google.com</domain>
        <port>80</port>
        <path>/value</path>
        <query>blah</query>
      </src>
      <tgt>
        <scheme>https</scheme>
        <domain>map.google.com</domain>
        <port>443</port>
        <path>/value</path>
        <query>blah</query>
      </tgt>
      <loc>C:\var\tmp2</loc>
      <x>blah</x>
      <y>blah</y>
    </mapIndividual>
    <mapIndividual>
      <src>
        <scheme>tcp</scheme>
        <domain>map.google.com</domain>
        <path>/value</path>
        <query>blah</query>
      </src>
      <tgt>
        <domain>map.google.com</domain>
        <path>/value</path>
        <query>blah</query>
      </tgt>
      <loc>C:\var\tmp2</loc>
      <x>blah</x>
      <y>blah</y>
    </mapIndividual>
    <mapIndividual>
      <src>
        <scheme>http</scheme>
        <domain>*.c.b.a</domain>
        <path>somepath</path>
        <port>8085</port>
        <query>blah</query>
      </src>
      <tgt>
        <domain>r.q.p</domain>
        <path>somepath</path>
        <query>blah</query>
      </tgt>
      <x>blah</x>
    </mapIndividual>
    <mapIndividual>
      <src>
        <scheme>http</scheme>
        <domain>d.c.b.a</domain>
        <path>somepath</path>
        <port>8085</port>
        <query>blah</query>
      </src>
      <tgt>
        <domain>r.q.p</domain>
        <path>somepath</path>
        <query>blah</query>
      </tgt>
      <y>blah</y>
    </mapIndividual>
  <maps>
</mapGeo>
```

I attempted doing in many ways, like XSLT 1.0, XSLT 2.0, but I know I'm making some mistake, and can't make it to working:

Approaches I attempted:

```
<xsl:key name="kPropertyByName" match="domain" use="text()" />
...
<xsl:template match="domain[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('kPropertyByName', text())[1]))]"/>
```

```
<xsl:key name="property" match="mapIndividual" use="concat(generate-id(parent::*), scheme, '|', domain, '|', port, '|', path, '|', query)" />
...
<xsl:apply-templates select="mapIndividual/src[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('property', concat(generate-id(parent::*), scheme, '|', domain, '|', port, '|', path, '|', query))[1])]" />
```

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="mapIndividual" group-by="domain">
    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

I've other code as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- not working -->
<!--
    <xsl:key name="kPropertyByName" match="domain" use="text()" />
    <xsl:key name="property" match="src" use="concat(generate-id(parent::*), schema, '|', domain, '|', port, '|', path, '|', query)" />
-->

    <xsl:template match="maps">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
                <xsl:sort select="src/domain" />
                <xsl:sort select="src/port" />
                <xsl:sort select="src/path" />
                <xsl:sort select="src/query" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
        <!-- not working -->
        <!--
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mapIndividual/src[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('property', concat(generate-id(parent::*), schema, '|', domain, '|', port, '|', path, '|', query))[1])]" />
        -->
    </xsl:template>

<!-- not working -->
<!--
    <xsl:template
    match="domain[
             not(
               generate-id() =
               generate-id(key('kPropertyByName', text())[1])
             )
           ]"/>
-->

    <xsl:template match="schema[text() = '' or text() = 'http' or text() = 'https']" />
    <xsl:template match="port[text() = '80' or text() = '443']" />

    <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The below items need to be considered:

- I've other transformations logic in place, and I'm trying to add the duplicate removal along with it, and don't want to apply on the output of first transformation.
- The tags are optional in nature, so it may or may not be present. In the above XML the first 2 `<mapIndividual>` nodes are duplicates though `<scheme>https</scheme>` is present in only one place for `<domain>photos.yahoo.com</domain>`. Similarly, the `<mapIndividual>` with `<domain>map.google.com</domain>` is duplicate though `<scheme>https</scheme>` and `<port>443</port>` may or may not be present.
- When the tags aren't present it should consider default values for key / grouping logic, like `<scheme>` can be either empty tag, empty string, http or https, and `<port>` tag can either be empty tag, empty string, 80 or 443.

Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: I would suggest to write one transformation step filling in the defaults and then a second eliminating the duplicates. You can use several transformation steps in a single stylesheet, for instance by using modes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you for the tip. Instead of filling in, I would prefer removing the nodes for `<scheme>`, `<port>`, etc which possibly can contain default values, and this will reduce the payload to process. I came across this post on modes usage earlier, but didn't understand fully: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863491/xslt-grouping-on-multiple-keys-using-muenchian-method

Comment: I don't see how you want to group and/or sort in a straight-forward based on non-existing data

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that runs the input through a first mode to strip the `scheme` and `port` based on the defaults your question describes and then uses XSLT 3's composite grouping to eliminate duplicates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode name="default" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="scheme[normalize-space() = ('http', 'https', '')]" mode="default"/>

  <xsl:template match="port[normalize-space() = ('', 80, 443)]" mode="default"/>

  <xsl:variable name="defaults-stripped">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="default"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$defaults-stripped/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="maps">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group 
            select="mapIndividual" composite="yes"
            group-by="src ! (domain, string(scheme), string(path), string(port))">
              <xsl:sequence select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6E/1

It is meant as an example how to approach it, I am not sure I have captured the exact requirements on stripping defaults or on using various child or descendant elements to identify duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for the approach. Is it possible for a XSLT 2.0 solution instead?

Comment: Drop the `xsl:mode` declarations and spell out the identity template in XSLT 2 and drop the `composite` attribute and use e.g. `group-by="string-join(for $src in src return ($src/domain, string($src/scheme), string($src/path), string($src/port)), '|')"`.